What is the proper way to repair/recreate the .shx of an ESRI Shapefile using gdal?
I can recreate the missing .shx file by using the gdal command ogr2ogr and specifing the config "--config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX YES".
But, although it recreates the .shx file it gives me an error: -nln name must be specified combined with a single source layer name, or a -sql statement, and name must be different from an existing layer.
I mean, seems like i'm not using the ogr2ogr command properly. So, how can i recreate it in the correct manner?
Full command
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -overwrite -skipfailures --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX YES file.shp file.shp


I think the output file name should be different than your input file name.

So, i cannot overwrite the file?

I haven't tested it, but ogr2ogr typically wants another output file.
